# how should I get bazel workspace set up?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to make bazel build a jar and an so file for a flutter project but every time I type 'bazel build' into the command prompt I keep getting

ERROR: The 'build' command is only supported from within a workspace (below a directory having a WORKSPACE file).
See documentation at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#workspace

I've read some documentation it seems like the solution is to create a blank file called 'WORKSPACE' but I don't understand where this file is supposed to be stored. here's a link to the documentation I read https://docs.bazel.build/versions/2.0.0/tutorial/java.html 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`WORKSPACE` file goes to the root of your workspace (source). It's the top directory for all your build packages and start of there absolute path you'd refer too with `//`. For instance if you had a tree like this:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── a_source_file
├── package1
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── other_source
└── package2
    ├── BUILD
    └── another_source
```

You would construct your workspace where all your packages converge (root they share) as:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
├── a_source_file
├── package1
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── other_source
└── package2
    ├── BUILD
    └── another_source
```

And your build targets could then be for instance: `//:a_build_target` or `//package2:another_target`.

Comment: I found a workaround which involved configuring the workspace in terminal (anaconda prompt) to build tensorflow. the problem is that I'm missing a package called com_google_protobuff.